# Viewing Workflow History in Workbox

Tags: workbox

I'm very new to Sitecore and am trying to learn what I can by clicking around the Launchpad so go easy on me! ;)

This question is about the workbox. Once I have approved (or rejected) an item displayed in my workbox, it disappears from my workbox. Is there a way to see the history of what I've done to items in my workbox, rather than just what still needs my approval?

I see that I can select an item from the Content Tree, go to the "Review" tab, and select "History" to see the workflow history of that particular item, but what if I want to see every workflow I took part in that day?

Comment: This sounds like what you need is single window report which consists of all the items which have been moved from a certain workflow, or in other words, also can be formulated as were modified today or yesterday, is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the wonderful world of Sitecore. You can learn something new everyday with it. You should be able to see the workflow as long as you have execute rights to the workflow steps. In the workflows group box in the workbox you select the workflow you want to view. You should see the item and a more link that will give you the history. Refer to this documentation for more info. Let me know if this helps.

https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/workflowreference-usletter.pdf

Comment: RReilley, thank you for the response! I guess the workbox can only show items that are currently in some workflow state and not completed items... From what I can tell, once the item has gone through every state of the workflow and been approved, it disappears from the list in the workbox. I was hoping for a way to see the items that had gone through the entire workflow.

Comment: I worked for one company were we overwrote the behavior and created a history page you can see from Experience Editor. I don't know if you have to go that far, but it can be done if you need to. :) Good luck.